# Adobe Premier CS6 'Unable to open file' coming from Cineform

Tags: premiere, mp4, avid

I just transformed a MP4 file coming from my GoPro into a MOV file using CineForm studio. It works great in MAC.

However, when doing the same on Windows, and transforming from MP4 to AVI, when trying to open the file on Premiere, I get an error saying 'unkown file or damaged file'.  I am guessing Adobe Premiere doesn't know how to open that AVI file, but at the same time it's weird because I can open it with Windows Media Player.

Anybody has experienced this or knows how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply update your Cineform installation and maybe also Premiere, this was a bug with Cineform and got fixed about 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a codec problem.  Is there a reason you don't just directly try opening the MP4 or MOV file?  Do those also have problems?  You shouldn't have to work with a AVI file in Premiere on Windows.  You need to identify the codec being used in the video and then install the proper codecs.  There are different types of codecs that can be used on Windows and it is possible that the codec that works in Windows Media Player wouldn't work in Premiere.  You need to obtain a copy of the codec that will work with Premiere.

If you do not know how to identify the codec, if you can post a small sample of video encoded the same way, it should be possible for us to identify the codec and it might help identify the problem as well if it is something more rare that isn't codec related.